# Should logs be included in the question?

Tags: discussion

I often see people (not specifically on [RaspberryPi.SE]) use sites like `pastebin.com` to post logs.

Stack Exchange has no control over these sites and these sites are free to place any ads on their site as they please. They are also free to remove the content whenever they please.

So, personally, I prefer to always include the log in the question (as long as it is possible due to the length). Code blocks get scrollbars when they need them. So, visually, it's not too bad.

What's your opinion on it?

---

This question came to mind due to this question:
[How do I install Jenkins?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/how-do-i-install-jenkins)

Answer (score 4):

Logs are often essential to the question, as there is no way to answer the question without them. We should accept the logs on an external site, but once answered, pull in the one or two lines that are actually relevant. Furthermore, we should encourage people to post their whole log, otherwise people tend to exclude something essential - especially when one error has caused another.

Comment: There's actually a post on [metase] about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70043/offer-a-stack-exchange-brand-pastebin

Answer (score 2):

I think that as long as the question/answer is not completely reliant on the external link then it is okay. Links should supplement content, not define it.

If answerers literally cant answer the question without visiting an external site then this is probably bad.

Comment: How about the question I linked above? The answer given refers to the log. Would you agree that it would be a good idea to pull in the log?

Comment: It would be best to put the relevant bits of that log in the question. No way does it need all of it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we should encourage Stack Exchange to develop their own pastebin-clone, which deletes entries once they don't have an active link on the SE network and guarantees the contents while there are active links.

Comment: I often wished for something like this to exist. Maybe a cooperation with some pastebin site, like there is with imgur.

Answer (score 1):

There are always going to be people overtrimming and undertrimming logs; it would be great if every question initially included precisely what is needed, but sometimes someone who is lost has to dump the whole thing someplace so those interested in helping them can quickly find the important part.

The suggestion to move that key part back here is a good one, though not always necessary if the problem is clear from the answer.